# How can I optimize my function not to repeat lines?

Tags: javascript, function, optimization, ecmascript-6

I am doing my project and decide to optimize it maximally! The purpose of my function is to randomly place an image.

*This is my js function:*

```
moveImage() {
  this.imgTop = Math.round(Math.random() * (screen.height - this.imgHeight));
  this.imgLeft = Math.round(Math.random() * (screen.width - this.imgWidth));
}
```

Is it possible to optimize it?
I don't think that I should use random twice...

Comment: *"i don't think that i should use random twice..."* Why not? Do you not want different numbers?

Comment: Are you trying to optimize for performance or optimize for readability? It seems pretty close to optimal in both regards already. If you don't want to call `Math.random` twice, you could always store the result in a variable, but this would result in very different behavior so think carefully about whether this is what you really want.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder i am trying to find some variants to write less... because of this reason! numbers should be different

Comment: moveImage(img, screensize, size) {
    img = Math.round(Math.random() * (screensize - size));
  } 


  moveImage(this.imgTop, screen.height, this.imgHeight)
  moveImage(this.imgLeft, screen.width, this.imgWidth)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Do you mean something like:

```
  const offset = ( available, size ) => Math.round(Math.random() * ( available - size ));

  moveImage() {
    this.imgTop = offset( screen.height, this.imgHeight );
    this.imgLeft = offset( screen.width, this.imgWidth );
  }
```

Where you just put the repeated parts into its own function?

Including the call to the offset function, this might actually come down to more characters than the original, so not sure if your own code is 'too repeating' to begin with.

Edit. Or even more compact:

```
  const offset = range => Math.round(Math.random() * range);

  moveImage() {
    this.imgTop = offset( screen.height - this.imgHeight );
    this.imgLeft = offset( screen.width - this.imgWidth );
  }
```

Comment: `const offset = (range) => Math.round(Math.random() * range); ... offset( screen.height - this.imgHeight );` -- Cut out a few more characters without getting into code golf territory.